# Tried to plot 10 subplots but only last 4 are displayed

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, subplot

I have the following program ,I tried to plot 10 subplots but only last 4 are being displayed,Is it possible to plot 10 subplots?or should i do the program for the first plots seperately???

```
lat=range(1,11)
frequency=[]
p=[]
x=[]
t=[]
fig = plt.figure()
with open('output.xml', 'w') as output_file,open('jacobians.xml', "r") as input_file, open('extracted.xml', "r") as input_file1:
for j in lat:
    l=8*j
    i=l-6
    a=0
    v=94*j
    u=v-92
    for lines in itertools.islice(input_file1, u, v):
        lines=np.array(lines.split())
        p.append(float(lines[0]))
        x.append(np.log(float((lines[0]))))
        t.append(float(lines[1]))
    for line in itertools.islice(input_file, i, l):
        line=np.array(line.split()).astype(float)
        #plotting
        ax= fig.add_subplot(10,1,j)
        ax.plot(p,line)
    del x[:]
    del p[:]
    del t[:]
plt.show()
```

This is the output I'm getting
[image]
I'm new to  this,any help will be appreciated.Thankyou

Comment: Why do you have a `4` as the first argument of `add_subplot` if you intend to have a 10 x 1 grid?

Comment: I tried adding 10 also but still only 4 are displayed...I have edited that in my question also..Thankyou

Comment: I think i found the mistake after 4 iterations "line" is not taking any value...How to tackle this??

Comment: What would you like to fill the remaining 6 subplots with, if the input file has only data for 4 subplots? Why do you even need 10 subplots, if there isn't enough data?